# match and print each selection from array

Tags: perl

I have a script which collects configuration data from a database and stores it in an array. I need to print find each interface and print it's config detail for a device. I will only post the parts that I need help with.

So firstly, here is an extract from the array:

```
track 2 interface GigabitEthernet1/6 line-protocol
!
! 
!
!
!
interface Port-channel10.1
 description Enclosure 1 - 3040-1b
 switchport
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 200, 202
 switchport mode trunk
 logging event link-status
 logging event trunk-status
 logging event bundle-status
 logging event spanning-tree status
 shutdown
interface Ethernet1/20
  description tx to something
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 200-300
  spanning-tree guard root
  speed 1000
  duplex full
interface Bundle-Ether2.1
 description Bundle link to something
 service-policy input qos-pol1
 vrf V17:vodanet
 ipv4 address 10.1.1.1 255.0.0.0
 encapsulation 250
interface Ethernet1/1
  description some interface desc
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 200-299
  spanning-tree guard root
  duplex full
  no negotiate auto
clock timezone GMT 2 0
line console
  terminal length 48
  ...
```

So each interface does not necessarily have the same amount of config detail following it. I basically need to take each of these interface configurations and print them individually. I will be storing these in smaller config-let flat files. So I need to print from `interface ...` till the last item before the next interface, but I am lost in searching. This is my latest attempt, but only works if I search for 2 different start/end strings, like so:

```
foreach (@array) {
    if (/^interface/) {
        $counter = 1;
    } elsif (/duplex/) {
        $counter =0;
      } elsif ($counter) {
            print;
    }
}
```

The problem here is I am missing the first and last string, and not all interfaces end with `duplex`. I was thinking of using the beginning of line `interface` and then each double white space delimited items after but unsure how. Can someone please help me in finding a solution.

**Edit**

So to clarify `array` it is simply lines grabbed from a database and pushed to `@array`

Comment: What are the array elements -- lines?

Comment: @zdim, yes, the array will be router config including acl's, interface configs, routing tables etc. I just need to grab the interface detail specifically which will be stored in smaller flat files. So the array is as you see it i the example, but including other items.

Comment: How do you tell the last item of the last interface section? (That's not the end of the file, is it?)

Comment: @zdim, that is the problem, there is no beggining or end of the sections, it can start and end at any point. will edit question and show examples.

Comment: @zdim as you can see in the edit, other config detail can follow, but will never be the same for any 2 device configs. Keep in mind we have different configs as we get Juniper devices, Cisco etc. Hence why I was merely thinking of using the match of interface with no space before it, then everything with 2 spaces means it is it's config.

Comment: OK.  Still, you have to somehow be able to tell where `interface Ethernet1/1` ends.  How do you know what the last line of that section is (where to stop)?

Comment: you don't know :) when the next interface starts, if means the previous ended. These examples are exactly as we see it. Some interfaces are in a shut state, so has less detail, others form a bundle, so have more info. The only thing that is a patern is the beginning of each item has no space before, then that items config items each have 2 spaces prior to the item.

Comment: So, you have an array, of lines. An "interface section" starts with a line `interface` and ends before the next such line.  Then you get to the last `interface` line in the array ... where does that "interface section" ends? Does it go all the way to the end of the array?  You must know where to stop for the last one.

Comment: @zdim that is the problem, you do not know, the last interface will be where the next line does not start with `interface` :(

Comment: That is not possible; then you couldn't solve the problem.  Take line `interface Ethernet1/1`, which I asked about above. You start reading lines after it ... until when? To the end of the array? To the line `clock timezone GMT 2 0` (unindented)?  If you don't know _that_, when to stop, you cannot have a solution for the last segment.

Comment: unfortunately that is how it is :( That is exactly why I mentioned that the only way we know the detail of an interface has stopped is that the next item in the line will start without a leading 2 spaces and not be named interface.

Comment: Ah, "_without the leading two spaces_" !  That's what I was asking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem: An array (`@lines`) has "interface sections" which start with an `/^interface/` line and run until the next `interface` line. The last section stops at the first unindented line.  Parse interface sections from the array.

One way: Find indices of each `interface` line in the array `@lines`. Then elements of `@lines` between successive indices are the interface sections. The last one is found separately.

```
my @idx = grep { $lines[$_] =~ /^interface/ } 0..$#lines;

for my $i (0..$#idx-1) {
    say "Interface:";
    say "\t$_" for @lines[$idx[$i]..$idx[$i+1]-1];
}

# The last interface section stops at the first unindented line
say "Interface:";
for my $i ($idx[-1] .. $#lines) {
    last if $lines[$i] =~ /^\S/ and $lines[$i] !~ /^interface/;
    say "\t$lines[$i]";
}
```

The last `interface` segment goes until the first unindented line, as clarified in comments.

Prints `"Interface:"` are there only to visually distinguish sections; the lines for each interface can be added to an arrayref instead of printing, for example. Tested on the posted sample.

---

Another way: Iterate over `@lines` and for each `/^interface/` line add a new arrayref to the array with all sections. Then the lines are added to that, last, arrayref. Exit on the first unindented line which isn't `/^interface/`

The program gets lines from the submitted file (or `lines.txt`), with the question's sample.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dump qw(dd);
use Path::Tiny;

my $file = shift @ARGV or 'lines.txt';

my @lines = path($file)->lines({chomp=>1});

my @if_sections;  # store arrayrefs with lines for each interface

for (@lines) {
    if (/^interface/) {
        push @if_sections, [ $_ ];  # add arrayref for new interface
        next;
    }   
    elsif (/^\S/) { last }

    push @{$if_sections[-1]}, $_;   # add lines to the last arrayref
}

dd \@if_sections;
```

Uses the handy [Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.104/lib/Path/Tiny.pm) to read the file. The module runs checks and croaks on failures.

The `dd` from [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) is used to easily show the data structure, for convenience.  This is an array with elements that are array references, so to work with it

```
foreach my $iface (@if_sections) { 
    say "Interface section:";
    foreach my $line (@$iface) {
        say $line;
    }
}
```

what can be written more compactly in a number of ways.

See the tutorial [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and
the complex data structure cookbook [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Comment: I have a question on the first script... I want to assign the line starting with interface to another variable, but I am unable to. I just want to split of the interface name from the rest of the config. I managed to do this in the last section simply by doing `if ($lines[$i] =~ /^interface/) {..` but it does not working i the first section.

Comment: @Jacob  The first snippet builds the array of indices at which `interface` lines are, `@idx`.  So the lines themselves are `my @if_lines = @lines[@idx];` .  When you index into an array you can use _a list_ of indices, (`@ary[0,-1]`, `@ary[2..5]`, ...), and you get the array [slice](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) (for hashes as well).  That "list" may be an array as well so `@lines[@idx]`.  Is that what you need?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply, my laptop crashed. Thanks, I think I get what you are saying, let me try that.

Comment: Thanks. I simply did: `$iname = $lines[$idx[$i]]`