# find a match and copy lines after in perl

Tags: perl

I have the following data..

```
interface 123
 item1
 item2
 item3
interface 456
 item5
 item6
 item7
card 477
 something foo
 somethig bar
```

Each interface starts at the very beginning of the line, where the detail of each interface has a space before the actual item. This is the only thing that can distinguish when the config detail of a ended.

I need to search each interface, and copy it and it's detail until the next line that does not start with a space.

So I would need to separate each interface with it's content detail, but not card. I was helped in a previous question with this, but the 2 loops are throwing me out and I would want to run 1 loop only as I do alot more later like deduplication, so 2 loops are becoming very confusing me.

```
my @idx = grep { $lines[$_] =~ /^interface/ } 0..$#lines;

for my $i (0..$#idx-1) {
say "Interface:";
say "\t$_" for @lines[$idx[$i]..$idx[$i+1]-1];
}

# The last interface section stops at the first unindented line
say "Interface:";
for my $i ($idx[-1] .. $#lines) {
    last if $lines[$i] =~ /^\S/ and $lines[$i] !~ /^interface/;
    say "\t$lines[$i]";
}
```

Can someone kindly help me do the same thing in a single loop?

Comment: How's the second solution from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50962511/4653379) ? It's cleaner and simpler anyway (I think).

Comment: @zdim it is indeed.. but doing `dd \@if_sections;` prints the data in square brackets and I cannot figure out how to split the data out later.

Comment: oh .. sorry for not explaining it. The `dd \@if_sections` is for convenience, to show it easily.  The `@if_sections` array has array references for elements, each having lines for an interface. So `@{$if_sections[0]}` are lines of the first interface etc.

Comment: @zdim ah... ok, so I can just grep the number of lines and then do? `for my $i (0..$#idx) {
print @{$if_sections[$i]}
}`

Comment: For instance, and then there are easier ways as well.  I edited that answer, I hope it's clearer now.  Please let me know if not, or if more comes up.

Comment: perfect, thanks a mill @zdim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $interface_line;
while(<DATA>) {
  if( /^interface/ ) { # start of new interface-section
    $interface_line = 1;
  }elsif( $interface_line && /^[ \t]/ ) { # interface-section followup
    $interface_line++;
  }elsif( $interface_line ) { # end of interface-section 
    $interface_line = undef;
  }

  if( $interface_line ) {
     print "Interface:\n" if $interface_line == 1;
     print "$interface_line: $_";
  }
}

__DATA__
interface 123
 item1
 item2
 item3
interface 456
 item5
 item6
 item7
card 477
 something foo
 somethig bar
```